# WinSCard SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH when connecting to Estonian ID card

Tags: c++, winapi, smartcard, winscard, id-card

I am trying to read the personal file of the Estonian ID card.

I need to send the following data to the card (from 
[here](https://eid.eesti.ee/index.php/Creating_new_eID_applications_old#Direct_communication_with_the_card)) in order to read records from the personal file (ie ID Number, name, etc):

```
00 A4 00 0C          # We choose root folder
00 A4 01 0C 02 EE EE # We choose folder EEEE
00 A4 02 04 02 50 44 # We choose file 5044, which contains personal data
00 B2 XX 04          # We read record XX (see table) from the personal data file
                     # The card responds 61 YY, where YY denotes the number of bytes waiting to be read
00 C0 00 00 YY       # We read YY bytes from the card
                     # Card responds ... 90 00, where ... is the requested data and 90 00 means status OK
```

However, the raw bytes are in the T=0 protocol, and the card is stuck in T=1 for an unreasonably long time before accepting T=0. The sequence of events is as follows:

1. Card is attached to reader
2. Program returns from `SCardStatusChange` and starts handling card
3. On trying to connect to the card (`SCardConnect` or `SCardReconnect`) the error `SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION` is received over and over, for around 5s
4. Then, on trying to connect, the error `SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH` is received for anywhere between 3 and 30 seconds, maybe more.
5. After that, the card connects successfully and reads the data.

**Can I somehow connect to it quicker in the T=0 protocol?**

A simplified version of my source code is as follows:

```
// NOTE: this is approximately what I do.
// I haven't tested this code yet - it's almost 1 AM here.
#include <winscard.h>
void readSmartCard() {
    LONG sCardErrorCode;
    SCARDCONTEXT sCardContext;
    DWORD sCardReaderStrLen = 1024;
    wchar_t sCardReaderStr[1024];
    SCARDHANDLE sCardHandle;
    DWORD sCardActiveProtocol;
    SCARD_READERSTATE readerState;

    sCardErrorCode = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL, &sCardContext);

    // error handling macro

    ZeroMemory(&sCardReaderState, sizeof(sCardReaderState));
    sCardReaderState.szReader = L"\\\\?PnP?\\Notification";
    sCardReaderState.pvUserData = nullptr;
    sCardReaderState.dwEventState = SCARD_STATE_PRESENT;

    sCardErrorCode = SCardGetStatusChange(sCardContext, INFINITE, &readerState, 1);

    // e.h.m

    if (readerState.dwCurrentState == 65538) {
        sCardErrorCode = SCardListReaders(sCardContext, NULL, sCardReaderStr, &sCardReaderStrLen);
        // e.h.m
        readerState.szReader = sCardReaderStr;
    }

    sCardErrorCode = SCardGetStatusChange(sCardContext, INFINITE, &readerState, 1);
    // e.h.m

    if (sCardReaderState.dwEventState & SCARD_STATE_PRESENT) {

        while (true) {
            sCardErrorCode = SCardConnect(sCardContext, readerState.szReader, SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
                SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0, &sCardHandle, &sCardActiveProtocol);

            // e.h.m
            printf("%x", sCardErrorCode); 
            // this will print:
            // 8010000b (for around 5s)
            // 8010000f (for around 20s)
            if (sCardErrorCode == SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
                break;
            }
            Sleep(1000);
        }

        // open personal file and read data, yay!
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For doing a connect the used protocol should not make a noticable difference in performance. 2) Cards supporting T=0 as well as T=1 are unusual enough 3) In case of doubt always use T=1, its easier for the application and more robust in respect to secure messaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long scouring of the internet, I discovered that no changes to the commands were necessary.

I simply needed to add an extra zero byte to the end of transmitted read/open commands, and receive the data as the response of the read command, not use a separate command to receive the bytes as well. (T=0 uses a "request data/read data" model, while T=1 just responds with the data, it seems)

I also needed to change all mentions of `SCARD_PCI_T0` to conditionally use `SCARD_PCI_T1` and make the `SCardConnect()` function accept T1 too.

I will post a decent code sample here later.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `SCardConnect()` for exclusive access to the `T0` protocol only, so if the card is in use then `SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION` is returned, and if the card is not in use but `T1` is active then `SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH` is returned instead.

When `SCardGetStatusChange()` reports a notification, you are only checking for the `SCARD_STATE_PRESENT` flag, but other flags can be present as well that are you ignoring, such as `SCARD_STATE_INUSE`.

If you need exclusive access to the reader, you will have to wait until `SCARD_STATE_INUSE` is cleared, and/or `SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION` is no longer begin reported.  Nothing you can do about that, unless you change your logic to allow connecting in sharing mode instead of exclusive mode.

If you want to connect to the reader regardless of its current protocol (and thus gain exclusive access sooner), you can ask `SCardConnect()` to accept *both* `T0` and `T1` protocols at the same time, by OR'ing them together in the `dwPreferredProtocol` parameter (see the example in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379473.aspx)).  Then, if the `pdwActiveProtocol` parameter outputs that `T1` is the active protocol, you can wait for a status change to the `T0` protocol before reading the card.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll improve the cases where the card is already taken. However, I'm unaware of how to perform the actions I need (navigate to folders, open the personal datafile, read records) in T=1, which prevents me from supporting the protocol. If I can't open the card in T=0 quicker, I'll research T=1 and see if I can do what I need there as well. (Exclusive access may wel be useless in this case, too, but I was trying to reach a deadline so I wanted to avoid any issues relating to sharing)